# Long time to solve numerical integration involved summation over large n

Tags: numerical-integration, summation

I need to solve this numerical integration to plot w as a function of x..

```
s = 10^-7 I; a = 3.14; w[x_?NumericQ] := 1/0.9 + (2*0.01)/\[Pi]*10^-9*Sum[(-1)^(n - 1)*f[[n, 1]]*
 NIntegrate[
  Cos[u*x]/(1 + s*Sqrt[u^2 - a^2])*(u*Sin[u/2])/(u^2 - 
      4*n^2*\[Pi]^2), {u, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 10000], {n, 1, 20}];
```

where:

```
f = {{6.41109*^9 - 8.09747*^7 I}, {9.38902*^7 + 
 1.52111*^8 I}, {-9.51822*^7 - 1.45977*^8 I}, {9.6633*^7 + 
 1.40777*^8 I}, {-9.7762*^7 - 1.36475*^8 I}, {9.8840*^7 + 
 1.3266*^8 I}, {-1.00953*^8 - 1.27382*^8 I}, {1.01067*^8 + 
 1.25779*^8 I}, {-1.02605*^8 - 1.21140*^8 I}, {1.03597*^8 + 
 1.18286*^8 I}, {-1.03759*^8 - 1.17169*^8 I}, {1.04575*^8 + 
 1.14535*^8 I}, {-1.0535*^8 - 1.11985*^8 I}, {1.06242*^8 + 
 1.09283*^8 I}, {-1.06928*^8 - 1.0686*^8 I}, {1.0796*^8 + 
 1.0328*^8 I}, {-1.0825*^8 - 1.00896*^8 I}, {-1.0825*^8 - 
 1.00896*^8 I}, {-1.0825*^8 - 1.00896*^8 I}, {1.08788*^8 + 
 9.86326*^7 I}, {-1.09275*^8 - 9.63506*^7 I}, {1.09723*^8 + 
 9.416360*^7 I}};

Plot[Re[w[x]], {x, 0.1, 1}]
```

I put my numbers rather than simple ones to be able to help me to find the reasons of my problem .My problem is the calculations take very long time can reach one hour to obtain eventually output dose not change harmonically with x, and dose not depend on parameters(s,a) as it is expected..Since I need to deal with large n, could you please tell me how can I enhance this code to get a reasonable result during reasonable time.

I work with Mathematica 11.1, Mac version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What stands out most to me is that you have `NIntegrate` inside of the `Sum`, meaning that you have to perform `n` numerical integrations for every single call of `w`. I am unsure as to the mathematical correctness of the following for improper integrals, but for finite integrals a sum of integrals is an integral of sums.

Thus, since `(-1)^(n - 1)*f[[n, 1]]` is not a function of `u`, it could be pulled inside of the `NIntegrate`, which could then be done outside of the `Sum` rather than inside of it, taking the parameters with it. This would look like he following:

```
w2[x_?NumericQ] := 1/0.9 + (2 0.01)/\[Pi]*10^-9*
    NIntegrate[Evaluate[
        Sum[(-1)^(n - 1)*f[[n, 1]]*
        Cos[u*x]/(1 + s*Sqrt[u^2 - a^2])*(u*Sin[u/2])/(u^2 - 
            4*n^2*\[Pi]^2), {n, 1, 20}]], {u, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
        MaxRecursion -> 10000];
```

The `Evaluate` call is there because the `Sum` term is the same for any `x` value, so it can be expanded during the function definition. However, this transformation does not have perfect agreement with the original over all points. It does evaluate much more quickly though, so messing with `NIntegrate`'s `WorkingPrecision` might be worthwhile, as the answer output does change significantly as the precision is increased.

Comment: Thank you eyoble!. I get this error ..NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. In order to fix it I put the integration over {u, 0, 10^4, \[Infinity]} but the error still exists.